# SES sends base64 characters in email body (instead of html) [ basic case]

Tags: amazon-ses

I am having issue with html sent vis aws-ses. Every once in a while it sends base64 text in email body.  I was able to capture a html that has this problem and could not figure out the issue - hoping if any one else has any idea on how to fix it.

I even created a test case to reproduce this issue.
Test case link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LWrnQowI4yLr1nYOSzcCF7_gH1sJ9_ht/view?usp=sharing

I am using java sdk to send email via SES and transmitting HTML to ses server but it sends base64 characters in email body as shown below:

=?UTF-8?B?PCEtLVtpZiBndGUgbXNvIDldPjx4bWw+CiAgICAgPG86T2Zm?= =?UTF-8?B?aWNlRG9jdW1lbnRTZXR0aW5ncz4KICAgICAgPG86QWxsb3dQTg==?= =?UTF-8?B?Ry8+CiAgICAgIDxvOlBpeGVsc1BlckluY2g+OTY8L286UGl4?= =?UTF-8?B?ZWxzUGVySW5jaD4KICAgICA8L286T2ZmaWNlRG9jdW1lbnRTZQ==?= =?UTF-8?B?dHRpbmdzPgogICAgPC94bWw+PCFbZW5kaWZdLS0+CjxodG1s?= =?UTF-8?B?PgogPGhlYWQ+IAogIDxtZXRhIGh0dHAtZXF1aXY9IkNvbnRlbg==?= =?UTF-8?B?dC1UeXBlIiBjb250ZW50PSJ0ZXh0L2h0bWw7IGNoYXJzZXQ9?= =?UTF-8?B?dXRmLTgiIC8+IAogIDxtZXRhIG5hbWU9InZpZXdwb3J0IiBjbw==?= =?UTF-8?B?bnRlbnQ9IndpZHRoPWRldmljZS13aWR0aCIgLz4gCiAgPCEt?= =?UTF-8?B?LVtpZiAhbXNvXT48IS0tPiAKICA8bWV0YSBodHRwLWVxdWl2PQ==?= =?UTF-8?B?IlgtVUEtQ29tcGF0aWJsZSIgY29udGVudD0iSUU9ZWRnZSIg?= =?UTF-8?B?Lz4gCiAgPCEtLTwhW2VuZGlmXS0tPiAKICA8dGl0bGU+PC90aQ==?= =?UTF-8?B?dGxlPiAKICA8c3R5bGUgaWQ9Im1lZGlhLXF1ZXJ5IiB0eXBl?= =?UTF-8?B?PSJ0ZXh0L2NzcyI+Ym9keSB7CiAgbWFyZ2luOiAwOwogIHBhZA==?= =?UTF-8?B?ZGluZzogMDsgfQoKdGFibGUsIHRyLCB0ZCB7CiAgdmVydGljYQ==?= =?UTF-8?B?